# Why cant I pass a python variable to a jupyter magic function?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am trying to create a widget button that will collect the values of other widgets and then use %run to execute another notebook with those values.  I am using %store to pass the values but it does not recognize the python variable with the value to pass and gives an error.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython import get_ipython
ipython = get_ipython()

def on_button_clicked(_):
    path=srch_loc.value
    with out:            
        path= srch_loc.value #returns the value typed into widget srch_loc
        print('Something happens!')
        print(path)
        ipython.magic("store path")

button.on_click(on_button_clicked)
```

When I click the button these are the results:

```
Something happens!
/san-data/users/$USER/
UsageError: Unknown variable 'path'
```

The print function recognizes path as a variable but the next line of code doesnt

I expect to not get an unknown variable message and if I run %store to see path listed with the correct value from srch_loc.value

Comment: I tried removing $USER to make sure it wasn't causing the issue but same results.

Answer (score 0):

Your `path` variable is local to your function. The IPython magic tries to access variables defined by the notebook code, which has a different scope.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Roland. If I add a `return path` at the end of the function shouldn't that put it in the same scope as the IPython magic?